# How to pass changed value to other component's methods in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

In the header component, let's call it `App.vue`, there is a select element:

```
<select v-model="locale">
 <option value="en">English</option>
 <option value="pl">Polski</option>
</select>
```

In the same component, the option selected by user gets processed in `watch`:

```
watch: {
locale (val) {
  this.$i18n.locale = val;
  console.log("locale: ", val);
  localStorage.setItem("userPrefLang", val);
  }
},
```

How can I notify other components (siblings, not children), let's say `Users.vue`, that the locale parameter was changed? I'd like to pick up the new value in the code (using a JS method), not with bound DOM elements. The new value should trigger the page reload due to changed locales. Should I use `Users.vue`'s watcher, `props`, or is there any other way?

Comment: maybe consider the usage of a bus for the data sync, or use vuex (https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication)

Answer (score 2):

One idea is to have a root component to manage the communication between the two peers, making your page look like this:

```html
<div id="root">
    <app></app>
    <users></users>
<div>
```

With this beginning, a next step could be passing the locale to users via props:

```html
<div id="root">
    <app></app>
    <users :locale="rootLocale"></users>
<div>
```

To update `rootLocale`, we could listen for an event emitted by app:

```html
<div id="root">
    <app @locale-changed="localeChanged"></app>
    <users :locale="rootLocale"></users>
<div>
```

Putting it together, here are the component definitions:

```js
var app = {
  name: 'app',
  template: 
    `<select v-model="locale">
      <option value="en">English</option>
      <option value="pl">Polski</option>
    </select>`,
  data: function () {
    return {
        locale: "en"
    }
  },
  watch: {
    locale: function () {
        this.$emit('locale-changed', this.locale);
    }
  },
};

var users = {
  name: 'users',
  template: 
    `<div>
      <div>{{message}}</div>
      <div>{{locale}}</div>
     </div>`,
  props: ['locale'],
  data: function () {
    return {
        message: 'awaiting change'
    }
  },
  watch: {
    locale: function () {
        this.message = 'locale changed'
    }
  }
};
```

And here is the root element:

```js
var vm = new Vue({ 
  el: "#root",
  components: { app, users },
  data: function () {
    return {
        rootLocale: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    localeChanged: function (val) {
        this.rootLocale = val;
    }
  }
});
```

Full demo is on JsFidde: https://jsfiddle.net/zfp5rLb7/1/

Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Vue has a way of doing this, `event bus` here is a link from the docs which tell you how you can do this
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication

You can also refer this helpful article
https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/

It can look something like this

```
var bus = new Vue()
// in component A's method
bus.$emit('language-change', 'en')
// in component B's created hook
bus.$on('language-change', function (language) {
  // ...
})
```